# Generar documento Excel desde Java

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy usando la librería POI de Apache para generar archivos excel desde Java. Esto funciona cargando los registros en un JTable y al oprimir un botón se genera el documento excel. El problema está en que necesito generar el documento ya formateado, es decir, los números en formato de miles y centrado a la derecha, por ejemplo. Esto ya lo hago con pocos registros, pero cuando son muchos(mayores a 50.000) tarda muchísimo en generarlos. **Obs. El límite de registros ronda por los 900.000 aproximadamente**, que son los reportes anuales que necesito obtener. 
Estoy buscando alguna otra librería para probarlo y comparar los resultados, si conocen alguna otra les agradecería que me ayuden.

Comment: No has pensado en darle el formato a la hoja? y las celdas?, existe la posibilidad de darle un formato a la hoja, y las celdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la librería que estás usando (POI) es lo mejor para tus propósitos. A veces el problema puede estar en un código no optimizado o en estar usando una versión de la librería no actualizada, [la última versión es de septiembre del 2016](https://poi.apache.org/#21+September+2016+-+POI+3.15+available).

De todos modos:

### Excel como Base de Datos

En Java puedes leer hojas de Excel como si accedieras a una Base de Datos.

Para ello necesitas añadir los drivers [JDBC ODBC](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjdbcjar.htm) a tu proyecto.

Te dejo un código de ejemplo, publicado en [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/AJDBCProgramtoAccessReadMicrosoftExcel.htm).
Se supone en el ejemplo que tienes una hoja llamada `Sheet1` y en dicha hoja tienes columnas llamadas `FirstName`, `LastName`. Consultas como si fuese una base de datos, obtienes un `rs`y operas con los valores devueltos.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:excelDB";
    String username = "yourName";
    String password = "yourPass";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    conn = getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String excelQuery = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(excelQuery);

    while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getString("FirstName") + " " + rs.getString("LastName"));
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
  }
}
```

---

### Otras librerías

Existen también estas librerías:

1. [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net)
2. [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net) (se ve un poco antigua).

Comment: Si, por lo que anduve investigando la librería POI es la más utilizada. Sin formatear los datos genera relativamente rápido esos 900.000 registros, pero al utilizar los métodos para formateo tarda bastante. Pero bueno, voy a seguir viendo. Ah, gracias por el ejemplo, está buenísimo.

Comment: @Carlos Cuando se formatean datos, a veces la diferencia es enorme según el **lado** desde donde formateas. No sé lo que ocurre en un tu caso, pero como norma, cuando se transportan datos **es mejor enviarlos/recibirlos de la forma más plana posible y aplicar el formato en el destino**. Si por ej. intentas crear un Excel desde Java lo ideal sería enviar los datos a Excel lo más planos posible y en Excel tener una fórmula o función que aplique el formato a la columna donde que recibe los datos. Supongamos un campo fecha, es más práctico enviar `20140430` que `Domingo 30 de abril de 2014`.

Comment: Correcto, mi caso es un ejemplo claro de lo que estás exponiendo. Mejor me tiro para esta alternativa, ya que formatearlos en el origen lleva un gran costo. Gracias por la molestia A. Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Has pensado en utilizar [jasperreports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)? Te permite crear plantillas con números en el formato que quieras, colores, estilo de celdas...

Comment: Si, uso tambien jasperreports, pero como la estructura es fija, la utilizo en otros informes. Pasa que para lo que necesito, la estructura en si es muy variable. En un inicio consta de 52 columnas, y de eso genero solamente los que en un momento especifico necesito. Pero si, esta muy bueno el jasper y es más agradable visualmente también.

Answer (score 0):

Otra librería útil para generar y manipular documentos Excel es docx4j:
http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré

Comment: Hola @Carlos si ésta o alguna respuesta ha solucionado tu pregunta por favor considera aceptarla como respuesta correcta haciendo clic en la marca verde de aceptación. Esto indica a la 
comunidad que has encontrado la solución y da repuetación ambos, la persona que ha respondido y a ti mismo. No es obligatorio hacerlo.

Comment: Hola @Kerten de hecho marqué la respuesta de A. Cedano como la correcta, porque cumple con lo que había preguntado. Saludos!

Comment: Ah vale. Disculpa, que no había visto la marca. Un saludo.